# Delphi: creating & displaying TImage on FormCreate

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, timage

Being quite a newbie, I've just had my first question answered ([Delphi: TImage.Create causes Access violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036590/delphi-timage-create-causes-access-violation)) to immediately bump into a new problem:

```
procedure TSelectorForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Loop: Byte;
begin
  for Loop := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    ArrayOfImages[Loop] := TImage.Create(SelectorForm);
    MainForm.MyImageList.GetBitmap(Loop - 1, ArrayOfImages[Loop].Picture.Bitmap);
    ArrayOfImages[Loop].Top := ...
    ArrayOfImages[Loop].Left := ...
    ArrayOfImages[Loop].Enabled := True;
    ArrayOfImages[Loop].Visible := True;
  end;
end;
```

When I display this form

```
procedure TMainForm.MyImageClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SelectorForm.Visible := True;
end;
```

the images aren't visible. What am I doing wrong?

I want to thank everyone for their advice. Hopefully, asking elementary questions helps others avoid asking them in future :-)

Comment: If my calculations are correct, this is the 200,000th question. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the Parent property of all image components to the form that contains them.

```
procedure TSelectorForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Loop: Byte;
begin
  for Loop := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    ArrayOfImages[Loop] := TImage.Create(SelectorForm);
    MainForm.MyImageList.GetBitmap(Loop - 1, ArrayOfImages[Loop].Picture.Bitmap);
    ArrayOfImages[Loop].Top := ...
    ArrayOfImages[Loop].Left := ...
    ArrayOfImages[Loop].Visible := True;
    ArrayOfImages[Loop].Parent := SelectorForm;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose that you have to add the single `TImage` components to the control-list of the current form?

That means: just because you're creating a `TImage` in code does not mean that it is actually added to the form's controls. You'll have to do that in code - however, I've not touched Delphi in a couple of years, so I can't provide any code right now.