# Delphi: array of TImage

Tags: arrays, image, delphi

This is my whole code:

```
    unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  Images: array[0..29,0..39] of TImage; //array
implementation

{$R *.dfm}
//form create
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var xx,yy: Integer; //local variables
begin
        for xx:=0 to 29 do
                for yy:=0 to 39 do
                        begin
                             Images[xx,yy]:=Timage.Create(Form1);
                             Images[xx,yy].Canvas.Rectangle(0,0,17,17);
                             Images[xx,yy].Left:=xx*16;
                             Images[xx,yy].Top:=yy*16;
                        end;
end;

end.
```

And I always get the error : "***Project Project1.exe has raised the exception class EClassNotFound with message "TImage not found". Process stopped. Use step or run to continue*** "

I have tried other codes on the internet like:
[Delphi: TImage.Create causes Access violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036590/delphi-timage-create-causes-access-violation) 
 http://www.delphi-central.com/tutorials/memory_game_2.aspx

Nothing helps!  Why is this happening?

Thank you.

Comment: When you create the images, use `TImage.Create( Self)`. Never use a form variable as a reference.

Comment: @TLama, suppose you are creating the form from a procedure with a local var of `TForm1`. What will happen ? The images will be tied to the global Form1 parameter and this is not a good practice. In fact very bad. The Images var should be declared within the form class.

Comment: @TLama, the other problem is that, if you create an instance of `TForm1` on the fly (in code) and assign it to a variable of a different name, you're in trouble. For instance: `var TheForm: TForm1;begin TheForm := TForm1.Create(nil); try TheForm.ShowModal; finally TheForm.Free; end;`. If at the point of `TheForm` being constructed, if there's not already an instance of `Form1` created, you get an AV. Always use `Self`, which will refer to the **current instance of the object**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure you get the exception at the line with TImage.Create? Could it be you have an invalid DFM file still containig a TImage instance which is missing from the TForm1 declaration?

Normally all classes used as children in a form or datamodule are automatically registered for streaming. As there is no TImage declared in the form and no other form of the application contains a TImage, there is no registration.

You can simply test by dropping a TImage onto the form.

Comment: Bring up your form. (f12) Rightclick: "view as text". Find the line: " object Image1: TImage" Remove this line and all the lines up to and including the next end. Hit F9.

Answer (score 1):

and if you want to show in form add this code to loop:

```
Images[xx,yy].Parent:= Self;
```